org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: JDBC exception executing SQL No operator matches the given name and argument types
I have a problem with joining tables.
First entity:
@Table(name = "deal")
public class Deal {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "external_id")
    private Integer ID;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "uf_crm_1712228470", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(value = ConstraintMode.CONSTRAINT))
    private DealEnumUfCrm1712228470 dealEnumUfCrm1712228470 ;
}

Second entity:
@Table(name = "deal_enum_uf_crm_1712228470")
public class DealEnumUfCrm1712228470 {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "external_id")
    private Integer externalId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "dealEnumUfCrm1712228470",fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Deal> deals;

    @Column(name = "value")
    private String value;

}


CREATE TABLE public.deal (
    external_id int4 NULL,
    uf_crm_1712228470 text null)
    
    
CREATE TABLE public.deal_enum_uf_crm_1712228470 (
    external_id int4 NULL,
    value varchar(255) NULL
);


Errors:
Error: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: JDBC exception executing SQL [ select d1_0.external_id, d1_0.additional_info, d1_0.assigned_by_id, d1_0.begindate, d1_0.category_id, d1_0.closed, d1_0.closedate, d1_0.comments, d1_0.company_id, d1_0.contact_id, d1_0.created_by_id, d1_0.currency_id, d1_0.date_create, d1_0.date_modify, d1_0.deleted, d1_0.is_manual_opportunity, d1_0.is_new, d1_0.is_recurring, d1_0.is_repeated_approach, d1_0.is_return_customer, d1_0.last_activity_by, d1_0.last_activity_time, d1_0.lead_id, d1_0.location_id, d1_0.modify_by_id, d1_0.moved_by_id, d1_0.moved_time, d1_0.opened, d1_0.opportunity, d1_0.originator_id, d1_0.origin_id, d1_0.parent_id_1036, d1_0.parent_id_1040, d1_0.parent_id_132, d1_0.probability, d1_0.quote_id, d1_0.source_description, d1_0.source_id, d1_0.stage_id, d1_0.stage_semantic_id, d1_0.tax_value, d1_0.title, d1_0.type_id, d1_0.uf_crm_1630408732647, d1_0.uf_crm_1659931017, d1_0.uf_crm_1665576409095, d1_0.uf_crm_1695724850752, d1_0.uf_crm_1705309507766, d1_0.uf_crm_1707119719817, d1_0.uf_crm_1707119819982, d1_0.uf_crm_1707119880366, d1_0.uf_crm_1707120091678, d1_0.uf_crm_1707127406194, d1_0.uf_crm_1707128138863, d1_0.uf_crm_1707143286, d1_0.uf_crm_1707145101392, d1_0.uf_crm_1707145189813, d1_0.uf_crm_1707145268405, d1_0.uf_crm_1707145551, d1_0.uf_crm_1707145811011, d1_0.uf_crm_1707145947108, d1_0.uf_crm_1707146079310, d1_0.uf_crm_1707146135461, d1_0.uf_crm_1707146163970, d1_0.uf_crm_1707146242324, d1_0.uf_crm_1707147038325, d1_0.uf_crm_1707147104917, d1_0.uf_crm_1707149878937, d1_0.uf_crm_1707150031009, d1_0.uf_crm_1707152276017, d1_0.uf_crm_1707152367859, d1_0.uf_crm_1707152404406, d1_0.uf_crm_1707153216673, d1_0.uf_crm_1707153235011, d1_0.uf_crm_1707153439, d1_0.uf_crm_1707153679546, d1_0.uf_crm_1707153772096, d1_0.uf_crm_1707154575, d1_0.uf_crm_1707155031500, d1_0.uf_crm_1707156037963, d1_0.uf_crm_1707156069398, d1_0.uf_crm_1707297535, d1_0.uf_crm_1707382738, d1_0.uf_crm_1707384877989, d1_0.uf_crm_1707385028092, d1_0.uf_crm_1707451667, d1_0.uf_crm_1707452385, d1_0.uf_crm_1707476888923, d1_0.uf_crm_1707723919930, d1_0.uf_crm_1707724024179, d1_0.uf_crm_1707728528, d1_0.uf_crm_1707800037114, d1_0.uf_crm_1707895852370, d1_0.uf_crm_1707895967501, d1_0.uf_crm_1708060379106, d1_0.uf_crm_1708060402635, d1_0.uf_crm_1708060445, d1_0.uf_crm_1708060567, d1_0.uf_crm_1708060584, d1_0.uf_crm_1708060603, d1_0.uf_crm_1708060868, d1_0.uf_crm_1708061134, d1_0.uf_crm_1708061198, d1_0.uf_crm_1708313343142, d1_0.uf_crm_1708321214833, d1_0.uf_crm_1708334626443, d1_0.uf_crm_1708349381, d1_0.uf_crm_1708515537, d1_0.uf_crm_1708516243819, d1_0.uf_crm_1708516309036, d1_0.uf_crm_1708517051530, d1_0.uf_crm_1708518301, d1_0.uf_crm_1708595011927, d1_0.uf_crm_1708669679267, d1_0.uf_crm_1709011170300, d1_0.uf_crm_1709622025399, d1_0.uf_crm_1709731780880, d1_0.uf_crm_1710223597123, d1_0.uf_crm_1710224893957, d1_0.uf_crm_1710487916092, d1_0.uf_crm_1710488751776, d1_0.uf_crm_1711371065591, d1_0.uf_crm_1711473165, d1_0.uf_crm_1711523487508, d1_0.uf_crm_1711711756588, d1_0.uf_crm_1712228861, d1_0.uf_crm_1712577743589, d1_0.uf_crm_1712732100959, d1_0.uf_crm_1712743989071, d1_0.uf_crm_1712812589150, d1_0.uf_crm_1713336354101, d1_0.uf_crm_1713356145130, d1_0.uf_crm_1713357357, d1_0.uf_crm_1713935333604, d1_0.uf_crm_1714037495819, d1_0.uf_crm_1714037563801, d1_0.uf_crm_1714981505052, d1_0.uf_crm_1715750633024, d1_0.uf_crm_1715751455743, d1_0.uf_crm_1715751549293, d1_0.uf_crm_1716804439763, d1_0.uf_crm_1716804677915, d1_0.uf_crm_1716891180821, d1_0.uf_crm_1716980441923, d1_0.uf_crm_1717411114268, d1_0.uf_crm_1718885974, d1_0.uf_crm_1719824872888, d1_0.uf_crm_1722327474834, d1_0.uf_crm_1722921968, d1_0.uf_crm_1723179741523, d1_0.uf_crm_1723444589386, d1_0.uf_crm_1723523640792, d1_0.uf_crm_1723548196932, d1_0.uf_crm_1723548203920, d1_0.uf_crm_1723548212779, d1_0.uf_crm_1724061685586, d1_0.uf_crm_1724062401335, d1_0.uf_crm_1724064846472, d1_0.uf_crm_1724065301336, d1_0.uf_crm_1724065337559, d1_0.uf_crm_1724065469381, d1_0.uf_crm_1724137625749, d1_0.uf_crm_1724154610834, d1_0.uf_crm_1724154709, d1_0.uf_crm_1724157882231, d1_0.uf_crm_1724157898767, d1_0.uf_crm_19_1712062072500, d1_0.uf_crm_19_1712141507808, d1_0.uf_crm_19_1712141559041, d1_0.uf_crm_19_1712141587575, d1_0.uf_crm_19_1712141624452, d1_0.uf_crm_19_1712141643098, d1_0.uf_crm_19_1712141660, d1_0.uf_crm_19_1712141726104, d1_0.uf_crm_19_1712141754, d1_0.uf_crm_19_1712141810001, d1_0.uf_crm_19_1712141831046, d1_0.uf_crm_19_1712141845465, d1_0.uf_crm_19_1712142270090, d1_0.uf_crm_19_1712142455246, d1_0.uf_crm_19_1712142493117, d1_0.uf_crm_19_1712142547310, d1_0.uf_crm_19_1712142579982, d1_0.uf_crm_19_1712145419, d1_0.uf_crm_19_1712160694051, d1_0.uf_crm_19_1712217371209, d1_0.uf_crm_19_1712825479173, d1_0.uf_crm_19_1712833019208, d1_0.uf_crm_19_1714638886241, d1_0.uf_crm_6661639123b1e, d1_0.uf_crm_666163914abe1, d1_0.uf_crm_666163924e9ba, d1_0.uf_crm_666163925df88, d1_0.uf_crm_666163926ae05, d1_0.uf_crm_6661639277ed4, d1_0.uf_crm_66616392862d5, d1_0.uf_crm_66a4f05551e8e, d1_0.uf_crm_a_t_group_id, d1_0.uf_crm_a_w_group_id, d1_0.uf_crm_closed, d1_0.uf_crm_comments, d1_0.uf_crm_created_by, d1_0.uf_crm_created_by_id, d1_0.uf_crm_created_time, d1_0.uf_crm_date_create, d1_0.uf_crm_date_modify, d1_0.uf_crm_event_date, d1_0.uf_crm_event_description, d1_0.uf_crm_event_id, d1_0.uf_crm_is_manual_opportunity, d1_0.uf_crm_is_repeated_approach, d1_0.uf_crm_is_return_customer, d1_0.uf_crm_last_activity_by, d1_0.uf_crm_last_activity_time, d1_0.uf_crm_lead_id, d1_0.uf_crm_modify_by_id, d1_0.uf_crm_moved_by, d1_0.uf_crm_moved_time, d1_0.uf_crm_mycompany_id, d1_0.uf_crm_order_ids, d1_0.uf_crm_originator_id, d1_0.uf_crm_origin_id, d1_0.uf_crm_parent_id_2, d1_0.uf_crm_previous_stage_id, d1_0.uf_crm_probability, d1_0.uf_crm_rfev231222, d1_0.uf_crm_rfev23870, d1_0.uf_crm_rfev26206, d1_0.uf_crm_source_description, d1_0.uf_crm_source_id, d1_0.uf_crm_tax_value, d1_0.uf_crm_tax_value_account, d1_0.uf_crm_tracking_source_id, d1_0.uf_crm_type_id, d1_0.uf_crm_updated_by, d1_0.uf_crm_updated_time, d1_0.uf_crm_xml_id, d1_0.utm_campaign, d1_0.utm_content, d1_0.utm_medium, d1_0.utm_source, d1_0.utm_term, in1_0.external_id, in1_0.value from deal d1_0 left join deal_enum_uf_crm_1712228470 in1_0 on in1_0.external_id=d1_0.uf_crm_1712228470 where d1_0.external_id=? [ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = text Подсказка: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

I have problems with joining tables, because the tables have different types of fields, foreign key and id.
And in the table i can't change the field types
Can anyone help with this problem?

How uf_crm_1712228470 defined in DB?

I added table fields

You can try ColumnTransformer on primary key, but I have little hope that it will work.

You mean , like this? :
`public class DealEnumUfCrm1712228470 {
@Id
@ColumnTransformer(read="external_id::VARCHAR",write = "?::INT",forColumn = "external_id")
@Column(name = "external_id")
private Integer externalId;
}`
this doesn't work either ;(

Only hope for you is native queries then.

Can yo add a view to DB?

Thank you very much, I use jdbcTemplate instead of view and write sql manually.

No luck with @Id and @ColumnTransformer. link
